# Add google recapcha in next js 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js13

I have the following code block from my contact form build with Next js 13 with typescript.

```
"use client"
import { Button, Input, TextArea } from "@/components/atom"
import { z, ZodType } from "zod"
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod"
import { useEffect, useState, useRef, RefObject } from "react"
import ReCAPTCHA from "react-google-recaptcha"

type FormData = {
  name: string
  email: string
  subject: string
  form_message: string
  captchaToken: string
}

const schema: ZodType<FormData> = z.object({
  name: z.string().min(5, { message: "Name is required" }),
  email: z.string().min(1, { message: "Email is required" }).email({
    message: "Must be a valid email",
  }),
  subject: z.string().min(5, { message: "Subject is required" }),
  form_message: z
    .string()
    .min(6, { message: "Message must be atleast 6 characters" }),
  captchaToken: z.string(),
})

const ContactForm = () => {
  const recaptcha: RefObject<ReCAPTCHA> = useRef(null)
  const [showToast, setShowToast] = useState(false)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [err, setErr] = useState(false)
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    setValue,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<FormData>({
    resolver: zodResolver(schema),
  })

  const submitData = async (data: FormData) => {
    try {
      setLoading(true)
      setErr(false)
      const response = await fetch("/api/contact", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
      })
      const res = await response.json()

      if (res.status === 200) {
        setShowToast(true)
      }
      recaptcha.current?.reset()
      setLoading(false)
      reset()
    } catch (e) {
      if (e) {
        setErr(true)
      }
      setLoading(false)
      setShowToast(true)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (showToast) {
      const timer = setTimeout(() => {
        setShowToast(false)
        setErr(false)
      }, 3000)

      return () => {
        clearTimeout(timer)
      }
    }
  }, [showToast])

  const handleChange = (token: string | null) => {
    if (token) {
      setValue("captchaToken", token)
    }
  }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitData)}>
      <div className="formRow flex gap-6">
        <Input
          label="Name"
          width="w-1/2"
          error={errors.name ? errors.name.message : null}
          placeholder="Full name"
          id="name"
          {...register("name")}
        />
        <Input
          label="Email"
          type="email"
          width="w-1/2"
          placeholder="Email address"
          id="email"
          error={errors.email ? errors.email.message : null}
          {...register("email")}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="formRow w-full gap-6">
        <Input
          label="Subject"
          placeholder="Subject"
          id="subject"
          error={errors.subject ? errors.subject.message : null}
          {...register("subject")}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="formRow w-full gap-6">
        <TextArea
          label="Message"
          placeholder="Message"
          id="form_message"
          rows={5}
          error={errors.form_message ? errors.form_message.message : null}
          {...register("form_message")}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="formRow flex gap-6">
        <ReCAPTCHA
          size="normal"
          sitekey="6Ldh6jgoAAAAAM44ieDQ6Nw1cvAWa5i2NhGjpV4a"
          onChange={handleChange}
          ref={recaptcha}
        />
      </div>
      <Button variant="primary" additionalClass="mt-5" submit loading={loading}>
        Send Message
      </Button>
      {showToast && (
        <div className="toast">
          <div className={`alert ${err ? "alert-danger" : "alert-success"}`}>
            <span>
              {err ? "Message sending failed" : "Message sent successfully!"}
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </form>
  )
}
export default ContactForm
```

I'm using **react-google-recaptcha** package to add google recaptcha in the above contact form.

I've also installed type `@types/react-google-recaptcha` for the recaptcha. I followed [this](https://www.getfishtank.com/blog/securing-nextjs-contact-form-using-google-recaptcha) blog post tutorial to add recaptcha in my app.

In local (my pc) recaptcha is working fine. But when i deploy to vercel  i'm getting build error. I've attached error message below:

```
Type error: 'ReCAPTCHA' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its type 'typeof ReCAPTCHA' is not a valid JSX element type.
    Type 'typeof ReCAPTCHA' is not assignable to type 'new (props: any, deprecatedLegacyContext?: any) => Component<any, any, any>'.
      Construct signature return types 'ReCAPTCHA' and 'Component<any, any, any>' are incompatible.
        The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
          Type 'import("/vercel/path0/node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'React.ReactNode'.
            Type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
              Property 'children' is missing in type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>' but required in type 'ReactPortal'.
  128 |       </div>
  129 |       <div className="formRow flex gap-6">
> 130 |         <ReCAPTCHA
      |          ^
  131 |           size="normal"
  132 |           sitekey="6Ldh6jgoAAAAAM44ieDQ6Nw1cvAWa5i2NhGjpV4a"
  133 |           onChange={handleChange}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1
```

I've also looked into the package documentation and couldn't find the solution. Is my setup wrong or this package incompatible with next js typescript ? I would be thankful if anyone could point it out.